# CardView - layout_height="wrap_content" or const value - performance impact?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, listviewitem

I have `RecyclerView` with `CardViews`. Do my list work slower if I set `layout_height="wrap_content"` rather then `layout_height="const_value_dp"` in `CardView`?

Answer (score 0):

No there should not be any performance impact of  `wrap_content` over `constant_value_dp` its only the programmers choice.

Comment: Do you have any sources about this?

Answer (score 0):

One thing is for sure,
if you use `layout_height="0dp"` or `layout_width="0dp"` with weightSum in its parent layout then it causes bad performance.

> Layout weights require a widget to be measured twice. When a LinearLayout with non-zero weights is nested inside another LinearLayout with non-zero weights, then the number of measurements increase exponentially.